# Invalid operation Exception while instantiating object of asmx web service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

I am trying to incorporate .asmx web service in my application.

For this I 
1. created a Class library project. 
2. Added service reference with the given wsdl
3. An app.Config was automatically created. The app.config that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="UploadWebServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="UploadWebServiceSoap12">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:xxxx/xxx/UploadWebService.asmx"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="UploadWebServiceSoap"
            contract="ServiceReference1.UploadWebServiceSoap" name="UploadWebServiceSoap" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:xxxx/xxx/UploadWebService.asmx"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="UploadWebServiceSoap12"
            contract="ServiceReference1.UploadWebServiceSoap" name="UploadWebServiceSoap12" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

After all the set up, I tried calling the methods in web-service in my function.

```
  UploadWebServiceSoapClient dpcClient = new UploadWebServiceSoapClient();
```

This is where is get an error

```
Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'ServiceReference1.UploadWebServiceSoap' in the ServiceModel client configuration     section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error. Also, I understand the binding created basicHttpBinding but what is  and an endpoint for the same was created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you've created service reference multiple times. First you created ServiceReference1 and then DPCServiceReference. You should change your endpoint configuration:

```
contract="ServiceReference1.UploadWebServiceSoap"
```

to

```
contract="DPCServiceReference.UploadWebServiceSoap"
```

You have 2 lines with this error.

If this won't help try deleting customBinding and endpoint with Soap12.

Comment: @Neha What exactly have you tried and what did you get? Does UploadWebServiceSoapClient implement DPCServiceReference.UploadWebServiceSoap?

Comment: I changed the contract from contract="ServiceReference1.UploadWebServiceSoap" to contract="DPCServiceReference.UploadWebServiceSoap" also I removed the customBinding from my app config. But i still get the same error

Comment: @Neha do you add service reference in same project that hosts mvc application? If not ensure that the actual web.config has this configuration, not app.config in different project.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I have been at it since morning. I just wanted to understand that why I have add all the information in the web config of the hosts mvc application and not just the app config of different project where I am adding my service reference

Comment: @Neha the web.config of mvc application is the only one used, app.config from other project is not copied to the output directory and is simply ignored.